# `combineReducers` - not able to understand of requirement and usage

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using `flux`. I have used `combineReducers` - all works. But what is the purpose of using `combineReducers` in the redux?

any one help me to understand by updating my code?

1. why should I combine Reducers ?
2. if I am not use, what is the impact ?

here is my code :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./countAddReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  value: rootReducer
});
```

[Live Demo with sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/43mxpqorz9)

Comment: read this example, I think it's can help:
https://codeburst.io/build-simple-medium-com-on-node-js-and-react-js-a278c5192f47

Answer (score 1):

`combineReducers` is used to combine all the reducers to one single store object, so that it can be used in every component.

In flux, you would have different Flux Stores to manage different state. With Redux, there is just one store, but combineReducers helps you keep the same logical division between reducers.

In your example,

```
export default combineReducers({
  value: rootReducer,
  removes: countRemoveReducer
});
```

you got two reducers  `rootReducer` and `countRemoveReducer`, and you combine these two make available in the components connect() method as `mapStateToProps`, where `mapStateToProps` have a state object which contains both these reducers.

Now, if you want to share state between two reducers then we cannot achieve it with `combineReducers`. For that purpose we need `redux-thunk`.

I have updated your code, https://codesandbox.io/s/lq87v947

Comment: so, both reducer will keep separate state with them?

Comment: both reducers state will be in a global redux state, which you can access in connect() mapStateToProps.

Comment: How can I share a state values in between the reducers?

Comment: you get a global object which will contain all the reducers state which you have combined, and you can access the state values by this.state.reducer_name.

Comment: can you show or share a example of sharing data between reducers?

Comment: @user2024080 for this you have to use redux-thunk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178247/discussion-between-user2024080-and-mcrist).

Answer (score 0):

It **separates the state** corresponding to a particular reducer into their own object.

Example:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userReducer from "./userReducer";
import blogPost from "./blogReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  blogPost: blogReducer,
});
```

When you start dispatching actions to either userReducer or blogReducer, the global redux state is just one object, but that object looks like this.

```
const reduxState = {
    user: {
        //state created by userReducer will go in here 
    },
    blogPost: {
        //state created by blogReducer will go in here
    }
}
```

Comment: some reasons, I require to generate a value using the current state of `user` in `blogpost` - so how `blogReducer` can know the current value of `userReducer` - is there a way or how to fetch the details from global variable can you detail me please?

Comment: @user2024080 There is a FAQ section dedicated to that question: https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers